# Can not add gradle DuplicatesStrategy INHERIT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

In my project with gradle 7.5.1 there was a error for the following task

```
processResources {
    with copySpec {
        from "src/main/resources/"
    }
}
```

Here is the error message. I have `application.properties`, `application-dev.properties`, `application-test.properties` files in my resources folder.

```
Entry application-dev.properties is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set.
```

So I was trying to add DuplicatesStrategy like bellow

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(Copy).all {
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
    }
}
```

After adding this the project runs but now I need another strategy `INHERIT`. If I replace `DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE` with `DuplicatesStrategy.INHERIT` I am getting the same error again

```
Entry application-dev.properties is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set
```

I checked(see implementation) the `DuplicatesStrategy` enum and `INHERIT` is a valid value.

```
package org.gradle.api.file;

public enum DuplicatesStrategy {
    INCLUDE,
    EXCLUDE,
    WARN,
    FAIL,
    INHERIT;

    private DuplicatesStrategy() {
    }
}
```

How do I add duplicate strategy properly?

Comment: What is the Gradle task that is throwing the error? Instead of adding the strategy to _all_ projects and _all_ tasks, try only adding it to the specific task you need. Additionally, why is `application-dev.properties` duplicated? There should only be one. Can't you delete one of them? Or merge them into one file?

Comment: @aSemy Please check the updated question, I have added the task. I can not delete dev properties file. I need both application and application-dev file and they needs to be merged. All project doesn't matter cause all tasks are here

Comment: Okay, thanks. I don't mean you should delete `application-dev.properties`, but the error message is saying you have at least two `application-dev.properties` files. Can you check how many are in your project? There should only be one.

Comment: @aSemy No problem, actually thats why we need the Duplicate Strategy. Weird thing is some values of that enum class are working and some are not.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why there is a duplicate to begin with. Why are there two `application-dev.properties`? Which files exactly are clashing? What's the full path of each? I think solving this would be more useful than trying to de-duplicate the files in the Gradle task.

Comment: As mentioned in my question I have `application.properties`, `application-dev.properties` and `application-test.properties` file. In `application.properties` file the common properties resides while for development environment `application-dev.properties` file hold additional properties and same goes for test environment. Now this gradle task copies those properties and use for building jar. So finally the properties mentioned in application and dev file are used for the build process

Comment: Okay so you have 4 properties files, all named differently. That makes sense and sounds reasonable. But then what is Gradle complaining about? If all the files are named differently, then there shouldn't be an error. Why does Gradle say there are two `application-dev.properties` files? If you find out which files are clashing then you'll be able to fix the problem. Try running `./gradlew build --info` (or maybe `--debug`) and searching the logs for `application-dev.properties`, maybe there's some extra info?

Answer (score 0):

As I could not find the problem I decided to go with the strategy `INCLUDE` which is same. [Duplicate Strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DuplicatesStrategy.html) has the following documentation

```
EXCLUDE Do not allow duplicates by ignoring subsequent items to be created at the same path.
FAIL    Throw a DuplicateFileCopyingException when subsequent items are to be created at the same path.
INCLUDE Do not attempt to prevent duplicates.
INHERIT The default strategy, which is to inherit the strategy from the parent copy spec, if any, or INCLUDE if the copy spec has no parent.
WARN    Do not attempt to prevent duplicates, but log a warning message when multiple items are to be created at the same path.
```

As my copySpec does not have any parent, I expected `INCLUDE` will be automatically used. But as it is not happening I decided to go for the `INCLUDE` instead of `INHERIT`.